# How do I reset my progress in Desert Golfing?

Tags: desert-golfing

I would like to reset my save data for Desert Golfing on my iPhone and start over from level 1.

Is it possible to reset progress in Desert Golfing?

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to just uninstall and reinstall the game.

Comment: obligatory: https://xkcd.com/1936/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DesertGolfing/comments/7hj8qo/possible_to_reset_the_game_by_deleting_the_app/) it is possible to reset your progress by deleting and reinstalling the app.

> Possible to reset the game by deleting the app?
>
> Yes, it should be - I've done it before, although that was a long while ago so don't know if updates have changed anything.

I just did this myself and can verify.

Answer (score 2):

The PC version is now available on Steam.

To reset your progress, find the installation folder and simply delete the `save` directory:

> %STEAM_DIR%\SteamApps\common\Desert Golfing\save

*(this directory will be recreated once the game is restarted)*

---

And, if you are on a crazy *hole-in-one* streak and don't want to lose all your progress after a tough hole, here is a nice batch file that will backup the `save` directory each time before starting the game:

```
@echo off

REM -- Directory location of this file
set THIS_DIR=%~dp0
REM -- Remove ending slash, if there is one
REM -- Great example from Strawberry Perl's portable shell launcher:
if not "" == "%THIS_DIR%" if #%THIS_DIR:~-1%# == #\# set THIS_DIR=%THIS_DIR:~0,-1%

REM -- Get the current date/time stamp
for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do @set "DT_STAMP=%%I" & call set "DT_STAMP=%%DT_STAMP:~0,4%%-%%DT_STAMP:~4,2%%-%%DT_STAMP:~6,2%%_%%DT_STAMP:~8,2%%.%%DT_STAMP:~10,2%%.%%DT_STAMP:~12,2%%"

REM -- Directory locations
set DIR_SAVE=%THIS_DIR%\save
set DIR_BACKUP=%THIS_DIR%\save-%DT_STAMP%

REM -- Backup the save directory
if exist "%DIR_SAVE%" xcopy /Y "%DIR_SAVE%" "%DIR_BACKUP%" /E /C /I /Q /H /R >nul

REM -- Start the game!
start "" /D"%THIS_DIR%" "Golf.exe"
```

---

*Minimalist, for script writers:*

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do @set "DT_STAMP=%%I" & call set "DT_STAMP=%%DT_STAMP:~0,4%%-%%DT_STAMP:~4,2%%-%%DT_STAMP:~6,2%%_%%DT_STAMP:~8,2%%.%%DT_STAMP:~10,2%%.%%DT_STAMP:~12,2%%"
if exist "%~dp0save" xcopy /Y "%~dp0save" "%~dp0save-%DT_STAMP%" /E /C /I /Q /H /R >nul & start "" /D"%~dp0" "Golf.exe"
```

Comment: Ha! There's even a `save3000.dat` in the `data` directory.

Comment: And a cactus! https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgyWL.png

Comment: I reset my progress. And the other sprites from "golf.png" just keep on showing up in different places: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ozdu.png

Comment: The cactus has shown up at hole #316 during the second consecutive play-through in a row. There is also a rock or something at hole #537. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUs0n.png

Comment: Oh wow. A cloud on hole #684. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBh38.png